# How to refresh a fragment from an activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

> I have a floating button in one of my fragments.On click of which an
>   activity pops up.Now the problem is when I go back from the activity
>   to the fragment the fragment does not auto refresh.Also I want it to
>   refresh on back pressed.
>   Within the fragment I have a refresh button in the action bar on
>   pressed of which I call a refreshFragment() method.Is there a way in
>   android that I can call a method from a fragment from within an
>   activity.
>   This is my refreshFragment() method code.

```
  public void refreshFragment()
    {
        Fragment fragment = new BillingFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentMg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTrans = fragmentMg.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment, "TABBILLING");
        fragmentTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTrans.commit();
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Billing");
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

> And I call it inside my on create view method as follows :-

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setFragmentRefreshListener(new MainActivity.FragmentRefreshListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshFragment();
            }
        });
```

> I even tried calling displayView() method of my main activity from
>   another activity by creating an object of MainActivity as follows:-

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                super.onBackPressed();
                MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
                main.displayView(1);
                count = 0;
                return true;
```

> But it gave me a null pointer exception.This is my displayView() method.

```
 public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    public void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new BillingFragment();
                title =getString(R.string.title_billing);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new StockViewFragment();
                title =getString(R.string.title_stockview);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new BhishiManagementFragment();
                title= getString(R.string.title_bhishiview);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new ReportingFragment();
                title=getString(R.string.title_reporting);
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new VendorManagementFragment();
                title=getString(R.string.title_vendormanagement);
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new CustomerMgmt();
                title = getString(R.string.title_custmgmt);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

> Any help is appreciated.Thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure this is the exact solution but try If u r using FragmentStatePagerAdapter use  @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    } and call notifyDataSetChanged of viewPager adapter like pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Raghavendra I tried your solution but it did not work for me.The view's are generated on back pressed but the data is not shown.what should I do in this case?

Comment: Can u post you viewpager adapter?

Comment: @Raghavendra please check I have updated the question with code for PagerAdapter

Comment: Which fragment it has to refresh can u specify the fragment name? Is that BillingFragment? If yes its not there in that adapter? can u check the adapter once

Comment: I am confused if the name of the fragment is same as the class name or is it the name we specify  here  fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment, "TABBILLING"); in which case it is TABBILLING.

Comment: Assuming your fragment is attached to an Activity (I'll call it Activity1) and when you click on the Floating Button, Activity2 pops up.

Go to your manifest and set Activity1 as Activity2's parent. For example:
<activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activity1">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.exame.Activity1" />
        </activity>

So when the user clicks the Up Button on the toolbar, the fragment will refresh

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I tried your solution but it did not work for me.This is what my code in the manifest file looks like. <activity
            android:name="org.bordetuts.com.goldmine.activity.AddInvEst"
            android:label="@string/title_addinv_est"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".activity.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes This opens the first fragment in my MainActivity.Is there a way I can open a certain fragment or just the previous fragment instead.

Comment: Let me see if I get this right. Are you trying to open a different fragment on your MainActivity after returning from the AddInvEstActivity?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I have a MainActivity which conatins a Navigation drawer which conatins 7 fragments.Out of which one of my fragments (Billing) has a floating action button on click of which a activity opens (AddInvest) when I go back from this activity the billing fragment is opened but with old data how can i update the data on back pressed/cancel is pressed/home back button is pressed.So basically I go from billing to addinvest and I want to update the billing fragment everytime I go back to billing from addinvest.

Comment: I guess you have to handle onResume event in that fragment  "@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); // Do your stuff....}"

Comment: Override your MainActivity's onResume method like @Sabari explained. and call your refreshFragment() method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you are trying to refresh fragment when coming back from an activity (that activity does not hosting the fragment which needs to be refreshed), if my assumption is correct please try the below approach, incase not please clarify the question with more info.

Try : Have a boolean variable in fragment and update its value true or false based on fragment visible state using its lifecycle methods.

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean shouldRefreshOnResume = false;

    public static SampleFragment newInstance() {
        SampleFragment fragment = new SampleFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public SampleFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, 
                                              container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check should we need to refresh the fragment
        if(shouldRefreshOnResume){
            // refresh fragment
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        shouldRefreshOnResume = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... Working Fine .. :) (Y)